# Key value paired array element returns "undefined" error while it is assigned the value in given index javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, hashmap, undefined

I need four key/value paired arrays for my code and I decrement the value for each array based on conditions.
In checking if the given value is bigger than 0 I randomly get "undefined" error in each of the four arrays and I do not know how to fix this problem

Here is my code:

```
Asett=[
    "A" ,
    "B",
    "C" 
]
var Bset = [
    "D",
    "E",
    "F" 
];
var Cset = [
    "G" ,
    "H",
    "I" 
];
var Dset = [
    "J",
    "K",
    "L"
];  
var cSets = [];
var vSets=[];
var dSets=[];
var fSets=[];

function initiate(){ //this function initiates the given arrays with defined elements and value equal to 10 
    for (var iv=0;iv<3;iv++){
        cSets.push({
            key: Asett[iv],
            rem:10
        })
    }
    for (var iv=0;iv<3;iv++){
        vSets.push({
            key: Bset[iv],
            rem:10
        })
    }
    for (var iv=0;iv<3;iv++){
        dSets.push({
            key: Cset[iv],
            rem:10
        })
    }
    for (var iv=0;iv<3;iv++){
        fSets.push({
            key: Dset[iv],
            rem:10
        })
    }
}
initiate();
generateList(cSets,vSets,dSets,fSets);  
function generateList(cSets,vSets,dSets,fSets){
    var j=0;
    var k=0;
    var l=0;
    var m=0;
    var taskL = []; // create an empty array
    var f=0;
    for (var i=0; i<27;i++){
        j=getRndInteger(0,2);
        k=getRndInteger(0,2);
        l=getRndInteger(0,2);
        m=getRndInteger(0,2);
        var combinations="";
        while (cSets[j].rem<=0) // I get cSets[j] undefined error 
              {
                j=(j % 3) +1;
              }
        combinations+=comSets[j].key+",";
        comSets[j].rem--;

        while (vSets[k].rem<=0) //I get vSets[k] undefined error
        {
            k=(k % 3) +1;
        }
        combinations+=vSets[k].key+",";
                vSets[k].rem--;
        while (dSets[l].rem<=0) //I get dSets[l] undefined error
        {
            l=(l % 3) +1;
        }
        combinations+=changeSets[l].key+",";
                changeSets[l].rem--;

                while (fSets[m].rem<=0) //I get fSets[m] undefined error
        {
             m=(m % 3) +1;
        }
        combinations+=fSets[m].key+",";
                fSets[m].rem--;

        taskL[f++]=combinations;

    }
}
```

In this code I expect my taskL array to get the combinations however I randomly recieve undefined error for each of the given sets (cSets, vSets, dSets and fSets) even though they are assigned value. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: What is `getRndInteger(0,2)`?

Comment: Its a function that gets random integer between 0 and 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change all of j=(j % 3) +1; these into j=(j+1) % 3
This way when your j is 2, it will be +1 and it will be 3 then %3 it will be 0 so you would not get out of bound exception.